# shortand for converting falsy values into undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is just me being crazy, but I have a `boolean` which I want to help me pass an argument to a method which accepts `value | undefined`, so instead of having to type:

```
<div className={loading ? 'isLoading' : undefined}/>
```

I was wondering if I there's any way to make that even shorter, for example:

```
<div className={loading && 'isLoading'}/>
```

The problem with the above is that it will return `false | value` which is not accepted.

I know this sounds insane but I just wondered if there's anything like that available out of curiosity.

I believe I could use `classnames` module in this case, but the above was just to illustrate the purpose here :)

Comment: `const myClass = { true: 'isLoading' };  myClass[loading]` ?

Comment: Well, in the case given `{loading && <div className="isLoading"/>}` would work too.

Comment: Not really shorter, but hackier. `loading ? "isLoading" : typeOf _`. Works as long as you never define a variable named _

Comment: @charles `void 0` would be shorter and more reliable.

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks. I didn't know that one.

Comment: @CharlesBamford That's never going to compile in TypeScript because you can't use anything that is not declared in TypeScript, also it's `typeof`, not `typeOf`

Comment: I thought I made it explicitly clear that it's bad.

Comment: You did, but you also said **Works as long as you never define a variable named _**, well, it ain't gonna work

Comment: @CharlesBamford And you don't seem to take criticism really well, congrats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *short* is the only measurement, i'll throw this into the game:

```
  ["isLoading"][1 - loading]
```